# How to send mail in phonegap ios

Tags: ios6, cordova

How to send mail from phonegap in ios.
how to send the input text and text area as messagebody in mail. 
please give me the coding.

Answer (score 0):

```
window.location.href = 'mailto:address@domain.com?subject=your subject&body=your message';
```